# Remove unique permissions on all locations on site SharePoint 2013

Tags: powershell, permissions, sharepoint-2013, unique

I want to remove all unique permissions on one site from all locations on it, whether they are lists, libraries, list items, folders or docs in libraries. All unique permissions must be removed.

I found PS script to delete unique permissions on lists or on site, but that's it, no examples to remove from all locations.

scripts I found are bellow:
for site:

```
$WebURL ="#"
$web = Get-SPWeb $WebURL
if ( ($web.HasUniqueRoleAssignments) -and ($web.IsRootWeb -eq $false ) )
{
  $web.ResetRoleInheritance()
  Write-host "Broken Inheritance Reset on web:" $web.URL
}
```

for list:

```
$WebURL ="#"
$Web = Get-SPWeb $WebURL
$ListColl =  $web.lists | Where-Object
{
  ($_.HasUniqueRoleAssignments -eq $true)  -and ($_.hidden -eq $false)
}
foreach($list in $ListColl) #if($list) #Exists
{
  $list.ResetRoleInheritance()
  Write-host "Broken Inheritance Reset on List:" $list.Title
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I managed to find a solution for my question.
Bellow is Powershell script code:

```
Add-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
#Variable for Web URL
$WebURL ="#" 
#get Web object
$Web = Get-SPWeb $WebURL

#Get Lists with Unique permissions - Exclude Hidden lists
$ListColl =  $web.lists | Where-Object  { ($_.hidden -eq $false) }
#Enumerate through each list and reset permission inheritance  
foreach($list in $ListColl)
{
 #Reset list inheritance
 $list.ResetRoleInheritance()
 Write-host "Broken Inheritance Reset on List:" $list.Title

 $items = $list.Items | Where-Object{$_.HasUniqueRoleAssignments};
 foreach($item in $items)
 {
  #Reset broken list item inheritance
  $item.ResetRoleInheritance()
  Write-host "Broken Inheritance Reset on List Item:" $item.URL
 }
$folders = $list.Folders
if ($folders.Count -gt 0)
{
 foreach ($folder in $folders) 
 {
  if ($folder.HasUniqueRoleAssignments -eq $True)
  {
    $folder.ResetRoleInheritance()
    $folder.update()
  }
 }
}
}
```

And that's it, this script removes all unique permissions on all docs, items, lists, libraries, folders on one site.
I used this page for start point:
http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/12/delete-unique-permissions-reset-broken-inheritance-using-powershell.html